# posting system PHP/MySQL has errors?, Warning: Illegal string offset 'description'

Tags: php, mysql

guys I have made 2 simple text inputs that store in my database and then retrieved using a foreach loop because I want to display everything in my table ( all the questions). With the current code I have I am getting multiple errors and would like some help on it please.

Also I am not sure if I refresh the page, will all the questions still be displayed in the browser or only when I click the submit button? If so please show me how to make it so that even if I refresh the page all questions will be displayed in the browser. Thanks

```
The Errors are Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 42
2


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 43
2


Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 42
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 43
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 42
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 43
h
```

```html
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


 $question = $_POST['question'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];

 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

 if($conn->connect_error) {

  die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } else {

  echo "Submit button connected to database!";
 }

 

 $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
 (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

 if($conn->query($sql)) {

  echo "it worked";
 } else {

  echo "error: " . $conn->error;

  exit();
 }


 $query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";

 if( $result = $conn->query($query)) {
      $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        foreach($fetch as $ques) {
            echo "<p> {$ques['question']}</p>";
            echo "<p> {$ques['description']}</p>";
        }
 } else {
  echo "failed to fetch array";
 }






}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>



<div id="submitQuestion">

 <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="question"/>
  <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASK"/>
 </form>

</div>









</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know that warnings and errors are two distinct things?

Comment: Which line is line 42 and 43?

Comment: Sorry, Line 42 and 43 is   echo "<p> {$ques['question']}</p>";
            echo "<p> {$ques['description']}</p>";

Comment: I know it has something to do with my arrays, just not sure how to find a solution

Comment: you fetch just 1 row. Use while($fetch = ....)

Comment: you mean just swap the foreach(...) to while(...)? im slightly confused

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p> {$row['question']}</p>";
        echo "<p> {$row['description']}</p>";
   }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

See more help in this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: thanks, it worked. Also when I refresh the browser The data is gone, only when i click ask the table is fetched. How would I write a script that retrieves all the data ( even when I refresh the browser the data sql table is displayed in browser)

Comment: Because the condition if(isset($_POST['submit'])) , it gets inside only if the form was submitted

Comment: I get it, so if i take away that condition will it display regardless?

Comment: Yes, only take out the 'SELECT' query. The 'INSERT' keep inside of it :)

Comment: i dont get how the data will display if I get rid of "SELECT" ? how else can I  select my table data then?

Comment: No this is not what I said.. I said to take out all the SELECT query OUT of the if condition, not to remove it.